# Combine Multiple Results Into Single Message Box

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a series of conditions that I'm checking, and based on the combination of results, a different Message Box should appear in my Windows Forms application.

```
if (pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix) 
    MessageBox.Show("CPL Filename Updated in ASSETMAP.");
if (!pklsizefix && cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix) 
    MessageBox.Show("OPL Filename Updated in ASSETMAP.");
if (!pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix) 
    MessageBox.Show("PKL Filename Updated in ASSETMAP.");
if (!pklsizefix && cplhashfix && oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix) 
    MessageBox.Show("CPL and OPL Filename Updated in ASSETMAP.");
```

How can I combine all of the possible results into a single Message Box, so I don't have to create a separate Message Box case for every possible combination? There are MANY more possible combinations -- I just stripped this down to 4 lines for brevity.

**UPDATE**:

Let me try to explain better. I am fine with creating multiple message cases, I am just trying to cut down the list, as there are 12 different bools I am checking, and there is a slightly different message for every combination.

One answer below is close to what I want, but I just get a blank Message Box when I try this:

```
var message = "";

if (!pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && cplpathamfix && !oplpathamfix)
     message = "CPL Size Updated in ASSETMAP.";
if (!pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix && oplpathamfix)
     message = "OPL Size Updated in ASSETMAP.";
if (!pklsizefix && cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix && oplpathamfix)
     message = "CPL Hash Updated in PKL.";
if (!pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix && oplpathamfix)
     message = "OPL Hash Updated in PKL.";

MessageBox.Show(message);
```

What I want is a simple list of the results in the Message Box like this:

```
CPL Updated in ASSETMAP.
OPL Updated in ASSETMAP.
CPL Hash Updated in PKL.
OPL Hash Updated in PKL.
```

Similar to what yo would see in the console if you simply printed out all results. There are many more unique cases than I am presenting here.

Here are some more examples of current code to show complexity:

```
if (pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix && !oplpathamfix && !pklpathamfix && !cplofnfixpkl && !oplofnfixpkl && !cplsizefixpkl && oplsizefixpkl && cplsizeamfix && !oplsizeamfix) 
    MessageBox.Show("OPL Size Value Updated in PKL. \nCPL and PKL Size Values Updated In ASSETMAP.");
if (pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix && !oplpathamfix && !pklpathamfix && !cplofnfixpkl && !oplofnfixpkl && cplsizefixpkl && !oplsizefixpkl && cplsizeamfix && oplsizeamfix)
    MessageBox.Show("CPL Size Value Updated in PKL and ASSETMAP. \nOPL and PKL Size Values Updated In ASSETMAP.");
if (pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix && !oplpathamfix && !pklpathamfix && !cplofnfixpkl && !oplofnfixpkl && cplsizefixpkl && oplsizefixpkl && !cplsizeamfix && !oplsizeamfix) 
    MessageBox.Show("CPL and OPL Size Values Updated in PKL. \nPKL Size Value Updated In ASSETMAP.");
if (pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix && !oplpathamfix && !pklpathamfix && !cplofnfixpkl && !oplofnfixpkl && cplsizefixpkl && !oplsizefixpkl && cplsizeamfix && !oplsizeamfix) 
    MessageBox.Show("CPL Size Value Updated in PKL and ASSETMAP. \nPKL Size Value Updated In ASSETMAP.");
if (pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix && !oplpathamfix && !pklpathamfix && !cplofnfixpkl && !oplofnfixpkl && !cplsizefixpkl && oplsizefixpkl && !cplsizeamfix && oplsizeamfix) 
    MessageBox.Show("OPL Size Value Updated in PKL and ASSETMAP. \nPKL Size Value Updated In ASSETMAP.");
if (pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix && !oplpathamfix && !pklpathamfix && !cplofnfixpkl && !oplofnfixpkl && cplsizefixpkl && oplsizefixpkl && cplsizeamfix && oplsizeamfix) 
    MessageBox.Show("CPL and OPL Size Values Updated in PKL And ASSETMAP. \nPKL Size Value Updated In ASSETMAP.");
```

Comment: Create a dictionary for mapping the 4 bools to a string (the message).

Comment: Can you please explain further? Sorry, I am new to programming.

Comment: I would fill something like `Dictionary<BitArray, string>` and process it further ([`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray), [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on updated question:

```
var updatedFiles = new List<string>();

if (pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix)
    updatedFiles.Add("CPL Filename Updated in ASSETMAP.");
if (!pklsizefix && cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix)
    updatedFiles.Add("OPL Filename Updated in ASSETMAP.");
if (!pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix)
    updatedFiles.Add("PKL Filename Updated in ASSETMAP.");
if (!pklsizefix && cplhashfix && oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix)
    updatedFiles.Add("CPL and OPL Filename Updated in ASSETMAP.");

if (updatedFiles.Count > 0)
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\r\n", updatedFiles));
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No file updated.");
}
```

If you want to avoid duplicate of messages, you can change from List to HashSet.

Comment: Please see my update above. I tried to explain my case better.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Separate string generation from invoking `MessageBox.Show`

```
var message = "";
if(...)
  message = "....";
else if(..)
  message = "//"

MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to simple omit multiple `MessageBox` calls. He seems he wants to avoid the separate cases.

Comment: This is close I think, but not working. See update above.

Comment: @jamlot if you are getting empty message box than none of the `if` statement conditions are met, because this way is logically equal to one where you directly call `MessageBox.Show` inside `if` statement body.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any kind of collection to collect the messages based on your condition and show it in a single message box.

Below code show it using List of string

```
var messages = new List<string>();  

if (pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix)  
    messages.Add("CPL");  
if (!pklsizefix && cplhashfix && !oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix)  
    messages.Add("OPL");  
if (!pklsizefix && !cplhashfix && oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix)  
    messages.Add("PKL");  
if (!pklsizefix && cplhashfix && oplhashfix && !cplpathamfix)  
{       
    messages.Add("CPL");  
    messages.Add("OPL");  
}
if (messages.Count > 0)  
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", messages) + " Filename Updated in ASSETMAP.");
```

Comment: Please see my update above. I tried to explain my case better.